# Are objects from an implementation factory method disposed by the DI container .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, inversion-of-control

When I register an implementation of an interface with an explicit implementationFactory, like this:

```
services.AddTransient<IDbConnection>(_ => new SqlConnection(connectionString));
```

The implementation is initialized when requested and disposed when out of scope by the DI container.

But will the SqlConnection also be disposed by the DI container when I do something like this:

```
services.AddTransient<IRepository>(_ => new Repository(new SqlConnection(connectionString)));
```

The intellisense isn't warning me about the undisposed object that implements IDisposable, but I don't think that's right.

Comment: No, in that second example, `SqlConnection` _isn't_ disposed by the container. If you combine both the first snippet and the second, you can get the container to take care of disposal for both.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But then this implementation will be used everytime IDbConnection is requested.
And I would like to use different connectionstrings in other parts of my application.

Comment: There are multiple solutions for this problem.
For example injecting only the connectionString and initializing and disposing the sqlConnection within the repository through the IDisposable pattern.

But I was wondering if there's another way using only the DI container.

Comment: You can plug in a third-party container for more advanced scenarios.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, container will not dispose in second case, because it does not know anything about this manually created instance:

```
class MyDisposable : IDisposable
{
    public bool Disposed { get; private set; }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Disposed = true;
    }
}

class Container
{
    public Container(MyDisposable d)
    {
        Disposable = d;
    }
    public MyDisposable Disposable { get; private set; }
}

var col = new ServiceCollection();
col.AddTransient<MyDisposable>(_ => new MyDisposable());
col.AddTransient<Container>(s => new Container(new MyDisposable()));

Container container;
MyDisposable disposable;
using(var scope = col.BuildServiceProvider().CreateScope())
{
    container = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<Container>();
    disposable = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDisposable>();
}
Console.WriteLine(disposable.Disposed); // true
Console.WriteLine(container.Disposable.Disposed); // false
```

But if you change second registration to:

```
col.AddTransient<Container>(s => new Container(s.GetRequiredService<MyDisposable>()));
```

both `MyDisposable`'s will be  disposed.

Using `[Autofac][1]`, for example you can resolve current lifetime scope and schedule manually created instance for disposal when this scope ends:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.Register(_ => new MyDisposable()).InstancePerDependency();
builder.Register(ctx => 
{
    var scope = ctx.Resolve<ILifetimeScope>();
    var dep = new MyDisposable();
    scope.Disposer.AddInstanceForDisposal(dep);
    return new Container(dep);
})
.InstancePerDependency();

Container container;
MyDisposable disposable;
using(var scope = builder.Build().BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    container = scope.Resolve<Container>();
    disposable = scope.Resolve<MyDisposable>();
}

Console.WriteLine(disposable.Disposed); // true
Console.WriteLine(container.Disposable.Disposed);  // true
```

Comment: Thanks!

I was searching for an elegant solution in situation where I want different implementation/instances depending on where the dependency is requested. I see now that I really need to start using Autofac.

Comment: @Jeffrey was glad to help! I'm sure some other containers can do something similar, but personally I've used mostly autofac =)